# Describing the pattern in which iterations make two, cyclic sets equal

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, permutations

$A = \{a,b,c,d,e\}$

$B = \{a,b,c\}$

$C = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

The first few iterations are as follows:

$1.$ $a,a,0$

$2.$ $b,b,1$

$3.$ $c,c,2$

$4.$ $d,a,4$

$5.$ $e,b,5$

$...$

I'm trying to figure out at which iterations we will have $x,y,z$ such that $x=y$ and $z=5$. I wrote a program to "solve" this problem for me, and I discovered that this happens at iterations $32,46,60,137,151,165...$. The problem for me is that I don't see how to derive this pattern. In particular, the following are true:

$32.$ $c,c,5$

$...$

$46.$ $b,b,5$

$...$

$60.$ $a,a,5$

$...$

Comment: Actually  maybe the confusion in our answers comes from your example: shouldn't the fourth iteration be $(d,a,3)$ and fifth be $(e,b,4)$?

Comment: I noticed you already had put up two other versions of this question, which you then deleted. I found that annoying, as I wanted to answer one of those, and had to chase through by checking your account to get to this version, basically the same question asked over again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I think your program is incorrect as the $32$nd iteration is $(b,b,3)$ and the first iteration of $(x,y,z)$ with $x=y$ and $z=5$ is $(c,c,5)$ at iteration 48.

In any case, the iterations you desire will occur when $n$ is a solution to the system \begin{align*}
n &\equiv 1,2\text{ or }3\pmod{15}\\
n&\equiv 6\pmod 7
\end{align*}

The first equation comes from the iterations $(x,y,z)$ with $x=y$, and the second takes into account the iterations with $z=5$.

Comment: Shouldn't $n$ be 5 mod 7?

Comment: Well the 1st iteration is $z=0$, 2nd is $z=1$,..., 6th is $z=5$, (etc. mod 7)

Comment: Thanks, @Casteels, I agree and used it to adjust my answer (with a reference to your comment).

Answer (score 1):

The least common multiple of the sizes 3,5 of sets $A,B$ is 15, so that $x=y$ will occur at any position $15k+1,15k+2,15k+5.$ For each of these, set it equal to $5$ mod 7 and solve.

EDIT: They should be set to 6 mod 7 since you start at step 1 with a 0 in column 3.
Thanks to @Casteels for pointing out this offset in a comment.

$15k+1=6$ mod 7 has solution $k=7r+5$, and $15k+2=6$ mod 7 has solution $k=7r+4$, finally $15k+3=6$ mod 7 has solution $k=7r+3.$ So the three solution families are
$$15(7r+5)+1=105r+76,\\ 15(7r+4)+2=105r+62, \\ 15(7r+3)+3=105r+48.$$